# Zend Regex Route > Track the api version

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am building a web service with zend and i am using modules to separate my api versions. Ex: "applications/modules/v1/controllers", "applications/modules/v2/controllers" have different set of actions and functionality.

I have made "v1" as the default module in "application.ini" file:

```
resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "v1"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
```

I have written the following in my bootstrap file:

```
$router = $front->getRouter();

$r1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('api/v1/tags.xml',
                array('module' => 'v1', 'controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'index'));
$router->addRoute('route1', $r1);
```

Suppose, if this is my url: `http://localhost/api/v1/tags.xml`

then it belongs to version 1 (v1).

But i dont want to write many routes like this one, so i want to know how can i track the version from the regex url and dynamically determine the api version to be used (1 or 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
$r1->addRoute(
            'json_request',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                                            '([^-]*)/([^-]*)/([^-]*)\.xml', 
                                            array(
                                                'controller'   => 'index',
                                                'action'       => 'index',
                                                'request_type' => 'xml'),
                                            array(
                                                1 => 'module',
                                                2 => 'controller',
                                                3 => 'action'
                                            )
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$r1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('api/(v.*)/tags.xml',
        array('module' => 'v1', 'controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'index'),
        array(1 => 'module')
);
```

This will automatically overwrite the module param, and should therefor automatically route to the right module. No need to use a plug-in with the `preDispatch` method anymore.

Comment: Sorry but i have to use the front controller plugin for some kind of validation purpose, and even though, the above modification does not work for me. I still goes to the v1 module controller.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It should work, I believe, unless your route is already caught earlier by another route. Have you defined other routes as well?

Comment: Yes, i defined many similar routes... anyways the solution pointed by vredniy worked well for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So far, i tried like this:

```
$r1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('api/v(.*)/tags.xml',
                array('module' => 'v1', 'controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'index'),
                array(1 => 'version')
);
$router->addRoute('route1', $r1);
```

And I could get an idea from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885109/change-module-name-in-zend-framework):

So now i used a front controller and in preDispatch method, i am setting the module name based on the value i get in the "version" parameter value, like

```
if($request->getParam('version') == 2 { $request->setModuleName('v2') }
```

But after changing the version in url to v2, it still goes to the action of controller in v1 module.